# What is the correct way of adding concurrent computation with side effect to a graph node in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I basically have a computational graph with an operation `A` like this:

```
     |
     o
     |
     A
     |
     o
     |
```

and I would like to invoke additional computation `B` while the tensors flow through `A` (in this case a variable assignment):

```
      |
      o
     / \
    A   B
     \ /
      o
      |
```

It seems tuples allow to do this, but I am wondering whether this is the best way of doing it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
v = tf.Variable(0)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
A = tf.constant(1)
A, _ = tf.tuple([A, v.assign(2)])
print(sess.run(A))  # prints 1
print(sess.run(v))  # prints 2
```

All of this is in the context of layer-wise computation in which the layer weights and other variables get updated as forward activations pass through them. An alternative would perhaps be to accumulate these updates in a `fwd_update_ops` list and finally call `sess.run([fwd_update_ops, bwd_update_ops], feed_dict)`. Are there other alternatives? What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: It's concurrent by default. Ie c=a+b will have a and b eval in parallel

Comment: But I am never calculating a+b. I want the action of assigning a value to the variable (`B`) to be a side effect of running a descendant of `A`. If the action `B` would not be connected back to the descendants, `B` would not be executed. I have updated the question title to be more clear.

Comment: Maybe tf.control_dependencies

Comment: Or tf.with_dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @YaroslavBulatov in the comments:

You should use [`tf.control_dependencies([...])`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#control_dependencies).

For instance, to make an operation `update_op` depend on `res = tf.square(A)` you can write:

```py
v = tf.Variable(0, name='v')
A = tf.constant(3, name='A')

update_op = v.assign(2)

with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    res = tf.square(A, name='square')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(sess.run(res))  # prints 9
    print(sess.run(v))  # prints 2, because v got updated
```

In terms of execution, the operations `tf.square(A)` will **wait** until `update_op` is executed.

```
       |
       o
       |  
       A   update_op
       |   /
     square
       |
```